# How to minify Javascript and CSS with command-line using minify tool?

Tags: shell, javascript

I'm not that versed in unix and I cannot have Java, so YUI Compressor does not apply, but I have this known [Minify tool](https://github.com/mrclay/minify), which will get a minified version of a JS/CSS file from a specific URI `/min/?f=/path/to/file.js.css`

Which unix commands may I use, using such method, to minify all the js/css files on the public_html folder, replacing all js/css files by their minified versions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520584/2072269?

Comment: @muru, it does not answer my question, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After searching and implementing it, I give the answer here through a bash file.

I use the npm packages [`uglifyjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs) and [`uglifycss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifycss) for compressing JS and CSS files respectively. I use command `find` to loop through those files. I assume js and css files are in a `js/` and a `css/` folder respectively.

```
#minification of JS files
find js/ -type f \
    -name "*.js" ! -name "*.min.*" ! -name "vfs_fonts*" \
    -exec echo {} \; \
    -exec uglifyjs -o {}.min {} \;

#minification of CSS files
find css/ -type f \
    -name "*.css" ! -name "*.min.*" \
    -exec echo {} \; \
    -exec uglifycss --output {}.min {} \;
```

This will minify all js and css files in respective `js/` and `css/` directories. If you want to exclude some particular folders or patterns within them use the option `! -name`

---

If you want to simply replace the minified file by the original file, that is, removing original file:

```
#minification of JS files
find js/ -type f \
    -name "*.js" ! -name "*.min.*" ! -name "vfs_fonts*" \
    -exec echo {} \; \
    -exec uglifyjs -o {}.min {} \; \
    -exec rm {} \; \
    -exec mv {}.min {} \;

#minification of CSS files
find css/ -type f \
    -name "*.css" ! -name "*.min.*" \
    -exec echo {} \; \
    -exec uglifycss --output {}.min {} \; \
    -exec rm {} \; \
    -exec mv {}.min {} \;
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to not rename but to have them like myScript.js and myScript.min.js ?

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf yes, remove the last two lines `-exec rm {} \;` and  `-exec mv {}.min {} \;`

Comment: npm `minify` doesn't have `-o` option that needs redirect `>`. How to make it work through changing ```-exec uglifyjs -o {}.min {} \; ```?

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install yui-compressor
yui-compressor finename.css > filename.min.css
```

Sources :

- [Humblix](https://www.humblix.com/ol91Gl/in-unix-linux-how-to-minify-a-css-javascript-xml-or-html-file-in-command-line/)
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321146/minify-tool-that-can-be-executed-through-terminal)

Comment: I cannot use Yum

Comment: I'm sorry ! I knew this is not the perfect solution, but I through it could help others. I hope that since December 2016 you found a solution !

Comment: This solution uses `yui-compressor`, which uses Java. The question stated *I cannot have Java, so YUI Compressor does not apply*